# rightBarButtonItem, leftBarButtonItem issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableViewController that I would like to have a left nav button, not the right one.  The rightBarButtonItem is grayed out and I cannot delete, nor am I able to add a left one. I guess I am a bit confused and do not understand how to do this in IB.  I have attached some screenshot that I think show my issue.

My Result, but i want the home icon on the left:

[image]

How IB is set up:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure if its just me, but I can't see the screenshots.

Comment: Hmmm, they show up for me. Not sure what I should do about that.

Comment: I answered your question but something just pop up in my head you do not push this view with a navigation controller, do you? I can not see the back button on screen shots

Comment: Why don't your drag home bar button item to the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add any bar button item on interface builder, create your button programatically,

If you want to use left button as a  back button use:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = btn;
```

If you have your own method write a `yourMethod:` function

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(yourMethod:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
```

do not forget to release button if you are not using ARC

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks for the help.  I was trying to do it all in IB, but I guess that can't be done.  Anyway, it does not matter too much, it works fine this way.